# Non defining or defining relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

"I've a labrador that has one eye."

Hi guys, is "that has one eye" a non-defining or defining relative clause here? 
Suppose I only have one labrador, is "that has one eye" nonessential additional information here, therefore rendering it a non-defining relative clause? Or is it defining my labrador? I'm a little bit lost.

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Seems very similar to this question on ELL https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122559/defining-or-non-defining-relative

Comment: [When a relative clause merely gives some additional information about the noun, it is called a **non-defining** or **non-restrictive relative clause**.](https://www.englishgrammar.org/restrictive-nonrestrictive-relative-clauses/) Such clauses are separated by pauses in speech or commas in writing. Hence in *My labrador, **that has only one eye**, bit the woman, **who lives next door***, the highlighted elements are non-restrictive (they provide more details about the specific dog/woman *already contextually relevant*, rather than ***identifying which*** dog/woman we're talking about.

Comment: ...and *My labrador that has only one eye bit the woman who lives next door* (without commas) features two ***restrictive relative clauses***, identifying which dog/woman I'm talking about (by implication, I have other labradors that don't have one eye, and there are other women around who don't live next door).

Comment: 'Essential' is only scoped as far as 'essential in well-defining the modified referent'. In  "The boy who was carrying a heavy rucksack was struggling to keep up," _who was carrying a heavy rucksack_ singles out the particular boy for the hearer. It is obviously required that there is at least one rucksack among the group referenced, and only one carried by a boy. // In "The boy, who was carrying a heavy rucksack, was struggling to keep up,"  the relative clause is non-identifying but giving additional (and very important) information

Comment: Okay guys. So from what you've explained it seems safe to say that "...that has one eye" in "I've a labrador that has one eye" would be a non-defining relative clause right? And if it is non-defining, would it be necessary to have a comma in there like so --> "I've a labrador, that has one eye"   Thank you all again, I really appreciate it. John

Comment: @JohnGaffney No: non-defining _that_ relatives are not permitted in Standard English, so your example can only be a defining one.

Comment: @BillJ thank you.

Comment: It's much better to use the terms 'integrated' and 'supplementary' rather than defining / non-defining, since integrated relatives are not always semantically defining. In your example there's no entailment that you have more than one Labrador: the integrated construction simply provides a succinct way of saying that the dog concerned has one eye.